# NameError: name 'username' is not defined in my form

Tags: python, pycharm, nameerror

```
@app.route('/register/go', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    global username, password, email
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'username' in request.form and 'password' in request.form:
        # Create variables for easy access
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        email = request.form['email']

    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = %s', [username])
    account = cursor.fetchone()
    if account:
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO accounts VALUES(NULL,%s, %s, %s)', [username, password, email])
        connection.commit()
        msg = 'success'

    # Show registration form with message (if any)
    return render_template('register.html')
```

I keep on getting error as "NameError: name 'username' is not defined" for the below line of code

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = %s', [username])
```

Comment: try adding username ="" in the start

Comment: I don't understand the logic. If the `SELECT` returns a row, that means the username is already in the table. Why are you inserting it again? Shouldn't it be `if not account:`?

Comment: @Barmar yes perfect thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to give `username` a value, even if you make it global. Use this:

```py
username = ''
global username
```

Comment: This will insert a blank username if there's no `username` in the form.

Comment: It will get rid of the error message, but make the program misbehave.

Answer (score 1):

The variable won't be set if the `if` condition fails. But if the form isn't filled out, you shouldn't insert into the database at all. You should move that code into the `if` block.

Also, your `if account` condition is backwards. You should only insert a row if the account doesn't already exist.

```
@app.route('/register/go', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    global username, password, email
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'username' in request.form and 'password' in request.form:
        # Create variables for easy access
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        email = request.form['email']

        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = %s', [username])
        account = cursor.fetchone()
        if account:
            msg = 'username already taken'
        else:
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO accounts VALUES(NULL,%s, %s, %s)', [username, password, email])
            connection.commit()
            msg = 'success'
    else:
        msg = 'Username and password are required'

    # Show registration form with message (if any)
    return render_template('register.html')
```